# codeigniter HMVC + Smarty: can we call module view routine from template

Tags: codeigniter, smarty3, codeigniter-hmvc

Just started using `HMVC module extension` and `Smarty` with `Codeigniter`. In HMVC, we can call module functions from a view to generate a specific view (in my case a modal dialog for login in case user is not logged in):

```
<?php echo Modules::run('module/controller/method', $param, $...); ?>
```

All this seemed to work pretty well before I started using Smarty templates. My question is -

Is it a good practice to call php routines directly from templates to generate a view?

Are there other alternatives keeping HMVC intact ?

One way I can do this is to create specific templates such as login_dialog.tpl and include directly in my base templates based on user login status. But, I feel it defies the purpose of HMVC and we should use modules to generate any view and not directly include them. I may be wrong. Please suggest alternatives..